# In Informix, is it possible to copy a database within the same server/host?

Tags: informix

Assuming a user has sufficient privileges on the server, is it possible to copy a database in its entirety within the same server/host, using SQL only (i.e. without having shell access to the Linux server running Informix)? Not just tables and views but also stored procedures?

On postgresql, it would be something like `CREATE DATABASE copy_db WITH TEMPLATE original_db;`

I ask because I am interested in creating a 'master' copy of a database that can be replicated on demand when running integration tests.

I am on Informix Dynamic Server 14.

Comment: There isn't a single 'COPY DATABASE' command. There is a command line tools to clone a database server (https://ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=utilities-ifxclone-utility). If your current server instance contained only the database you wished to copy, you could use this (but it relies primarily on shell access). There are not many alternatives other than `dbexport` of the database and then `dbimport` of the database when you need to re-instantiate it (a process that needs shell access). You might be able to use SPL and the SYSTEM statement to run the shell commands.